# How to release control of process thread in C#

Tags: c#, exe

I have a tool (created in C#) that launches another application using Process.start. This second application is a standalone application handling some external hardware using dlls and APIs.

Now whats happening is, when I launch the standalone application, it doesn't work until I copy paste all dll files (that are required by standalone application) in my tool's folder otherwise standalone application throws errors saying dll's missing.

It is also causing some performance issue with the standalone application too.

My assumption is : Because primary execution thread is from my tool and thus all spawned threads requires dll in the base thread (my tool's) folder. I don't want this. I am not sure what I have to do in this scenario.

If the only way to launch exe file in C# is using Process.start then how can I release the thread so that my tool don't track the standalone application ? (in case my assumption is correct)
If there is any other way to launch the exe file, please do let me know.

Help is much appreciated.
Kind Regards

Comment: Show us the code for launching your process. What is the directory you are launching your process from? is it the same as your applications directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you [set WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) appropriately?

It should be set to the location where your "another application" is located.

Comment: Correct, I ignored this simple thing while declaring the process.